# Can I implement an AWS lambda (Serverless) in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can I create a function with aws lambda and put it in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Is it an incongruity? because AWS is a serverless and Beanstalk is a PaaS?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put lambda function itself in beanstalk but you can use same code in beanstalk the way you use any other code. It will not be lambda function itself but a different code block which you can use as service